# C/C++ editors different indents using tab key compare to tab chars already embedded

Tags: eclipse, tabs, indentation, spaces

In Eclipse Mars and later, I want tab characters that are already present in the text to display as 8 spaces, but whenever I press the tab key I want to insert 2 real space characters.  Is it possible to set eclipse to display embedded tab chars as one indent setting and yet insert spaces on a different indent setting?

Comment: Best thing to do (my personal opinion) is to always use tab to spaces option. I don't think you can do what you want to do, except to manually change formatting on the original file.

Comment: Would be good if I could do what I want as I am maintaining code with embedded tabs which were clearly designed to replace 8 spaces.  If I change them all to spaces I end up with a large mercurial commit for no significant change - maybe a feature request for future Eclipse versions

Comment: @SteveM84 *I end up with a large mercurial commit for no significant change*  That's what CM systems such as mercurial are *for*.

Comment: maybe so, but then someone else edits the code and replaces all spaces with tabs and commits again.  That's not what im looking for, I just want Eclipse to interpret the tabs in one way, and interpret my pressing the tab key in a different way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no. The only available generic and common settings are in Preferences > General > Text Editor, and you have:

- `Displayed tab width` which allows to set the number of spaces used to render tabs (if you indent with tabs), or the number of spaces to insert on tab (if you indent with spaces)
- `insert spaces for tabs` to decide whether to indent with tabs or spaces.

But some specific editors (HTML, XML, CSS...) allows to somehow override this settings and give more control on tabs. You can usually find them in Preferences, then searching for `tab` or `formatter`. Those settings are specific to one kind of editor and not propagated across all editors. But maybe that can be enough for your use-case.

If you want something more generic, feel free to open an enhancement request to bugs.eclipse.org.